# Directory listFiles, but get null

Tags: android

I use below code to get file list:

```
File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if(folder.isDirectory() ) {
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    int count = files.length;
}
```

But files.length get error message below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

I have check there exist files.
Even if there is no file, it should get 0, but not error.
How can I modify it?

Comment: do you have the permissions to read the content of getExternalStorageDirectory?

Comment: I already add "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>"

Comment: if the folder is empty, listFiles returns null. It is the expected behaviour. Do you have files on it ?

Comment: I have file in the folder.

Comment: Did you ever see one without files or folders? I didn't.

Comment: So check for null before use. Null will only happen without permission.

Comment: But there are files and folder, it should not get null.

Comment: In which folder? What is folder.getAbsolutePath(): ? File::list() gives files and folders. File::listFiles() gives only files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062035/getting-nullpointer-exception-with-file-listfiles