# ListFile is null after updating to Oreo

Tags: java, android, file, android-tv

The app doesn't works after my mibox 4k update to android Oreo

The code lookup external storage

```
    private String[] getUsbStoragePaths()
{
    List<String> result  = new ArrayList<>();
    File storageDir = new File("/storage");
    if(storageDir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] subDir = storageDir.listFiles();
        for(File dir : subDir) {
            if(dir.canRead()) {
                result.add(dir.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
}


private List<File> getSubDirs(String path) {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
    File root = new File(path);
    if (root.exists() && root.canRead()) {
        File[] subDirs = root.listFiles(); ->>>>>> alway null

        if (subDirs !=null)
        {
            for(File dir: subDirs)
            {
                if (dir.isDirectory() && dir.canRead())
                {
                    result.add(dir);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

my usb storage has sub folder
Root
----SubDir1
----SubDir2
----SubDir3
----File1

permission in app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and request permission in runtime

```
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    if (!hasPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
        !hasPermission(, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
}
    private boolean hasPermission(final String permission) {
        return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().checkPermission(
            permission, getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    }   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Other things
    requestStoragePermission();
}
```

The result of getSubDirs method is empty, 
File[] subDirs = root.listFiles(); ->>>>>> alway null

Comment: File[] subDirs = root.listFiles(); ->>>>>> alway null.

'listFiles' Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null.
This root file is not the directory i guess, Please have a look.


1. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#listFiles()

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062035/getting-nullpointer-exception-with-file-listfiles

Comment: @Ankita-user3449434 This root file is directory, the path is "/storage/16 digit'

Comment: it works with  getSubDirs("/storage/emulated/0/"), but not work with getSubDirs("/storage/39EB...../")

Comment: The Android Oreo has many bugs on Mibox 4k devices. Now it has been changed status to beta

Answer (score 0):

```
This code will give you files which are stored inside directory.

String pattern = ".png";    
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Your directory name");
            File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
            if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {

                for (File file : fileList) {
                     //if you need particular file format than check with that otherwise remove it.
                    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(pattern)) {
                       //
                    }
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
Change target from 25 to 26
But can not support unicode name